# How to get the dynamic segment of the url in Ember.js?

Tags: ember.js

Sometimes, it's harder to get the dynamic segment at the very last part of the url in Ember.js. You can't directly call the `:dynamic_segment_name`.

Answer (score 0):

You can do:

```
window.location.href.split('/').pop()
```

To get it directly.